# What happens with my pc with RAID 1 just after a single hdd failure?

Tags: raid-1

I just was wondering what would happen immediately after a hdd failure occurs in a hardware raid 1 array? Will the pc continue to work with only one hdd?

Comment: I would hope that *immediately* after, you would get a disk failure alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Will the pc continue to work with only one hdd?

Yes, the array will continue to operate so long as at least one member drive is operational.

> **RAID 1**
>
> RAID 1 consists of an exact copy (or mirror) of a set of data on two
> or more disks; a classic RAID 1 mirrored pair contains two disks. This
> configuration offers no parity, striping, or spanning of disk space
> across multiple disks, since the data is mirrored on all disks
> belonging to the array, and the array can only be as big as the
> smallest member disk. This layout is useful when read performance or
> reliability is more important than write performance or the resulting
> data storage capacity.
>
> **The array will continue to operate so long as at least one member drive is operational.**
>
> <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Source [Standard RAID levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1)